# No sound in headphones (weird case)?

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, audacity

On Ubuntu 14.04 - I downloaded and opened Audacity for the first time, and now no sound will come through the headphone jack. I have tried every method I've seen - force reloading alsa, adjusting alsamixer levels and resetting pulseaudio with a series of terminal commands. I don't know what causes this, but I am 100% sure that it was fine before opening Audacity, and didn't work afterwards. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

Open Audacity and change the microphone source in the drop-down menu from `sysdefault: Headphone Mic:0` to `sysdefault: Internal Mic:0`